# Android Phone, get temperature, voltage and amperage

Tags: android, cordova, battery

Is it possible to get this three values on an Anroid Phone? I am using cordova and want to add a feature where you can see this values. Also if its possible to see and get this value, is there a plugin for cordova to do that?

Comment: these two plugins might help you: [batterie](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-battery-status/blob/master/doc/de/index.md) und [temperature](https://github.com/fabiorogeriosj/cordova-plugin-sensors). To monitor amperage it seems that android's apis do not support this.

Comment: ok that is a nice tipp but the second plugin, is it only for ionic?

Comment: @Number_987 No, it is just an code example using Ionic.

Comment: It makes sense that current isn't available as it is platform and battery depended (e.g. Samsung Galaxy sZ with a something mAh battery). Why you want it? If it is for doing hardware tests, you can replace the battery with an external power source and directly measure the current.

Comment: no its an official app

Comment: Did you came up with a solution for this?